# Redirecting area's default action to a single url

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-areas

OK, I should know this...but...I'm reaching out because I'm banging my head against the wall.

There is an MVC area, let's call it "store". There is a controller, let's call it "home". There is an action, let's call it "index". The following urls bring up the the same page:

/store/home/index

/store/home/

For SEO purposes I'd like to limit it "/store/home/". How does one do that?

Comment: Have you tried this? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5.aspx#route-areas

Answer (score 0):

If you have already released your web site with this URL, the proper way to do it is to use a 301 redirect. It is the only way to ensure that any links to the `/store/home/index` route don't instantly become dead links and therefore stop counting toward your SEO score. This can be done using the [URL rewrite module of IIS](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module).

Alternatively, you could just add a [canonical tag](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en) to the page pointing referring to the `/store/home/` URL.

However, if you have not yet released the web site, you can add a route that goes directly to a custom 404 page.

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
{
    context.MapRoute(
        "Store_Non_Match",
        "store/home/index",
        new { controller = "System", action = "Status404"}
    ).DataTokens["area"] = "";

    context.MapRoute(
        "Store_default",
        "store/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

And then in your site, make a system controller to return a 404 page and status.

```
public class SystemController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /System/Status301/?url=(some url)

    public ActionResult Status301(string url)
    {
        Response.CacheControl = "no-cache";
        Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.MovedPermanently;
        Response.RedirectLocation = url;

        ViewBag.DestinationUrl = url;
        return View();
    }

    //
    // GET: /not-found

    public ActionResult Status404()
    {
        Response.CacheControl = "no-cache";
        Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound;

        return View();
    }
}
```

Note the above controller also demonstrates how you could use a 301 redirect within the application as an alternative to the IIS rewrite module. This is handy if you have URLs that you know you will retire over time and you want to do it automatically from an action within the application. Not all browsers obey the 301 redirect, so my solution is to return a view that attempts to do both a JavaScript and meta-refresh redirect after 5 seconds, and if all else fails it has a hyperlink to the page the user can click on.

```
// Status301.cshtml
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Page Moved";
}
@section MetaRefresh {
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5;@ViewBag.DestinationUrl" />
}

<h2 class="error">Page Moved</h2>

This page has moved. Click this link if you are not redirected in 5 seconds: <a href="@ViewBag.DestinationUrl">@ViewBag.DestinationUrl</a>.

<script>
    //<!--
    setTimeout(function () {
        window.location = "@ViewBag.DestinationUrl";
    }, 5000);
    //-->
</script>
```